# Knockout native templating

Tags: knockout.js

I'm planning to convert a Knockout based page to native templating. However, I have a couple of questions about the limitations of native templating compared to jQuery Templates.

With Knockout native templating can I reference a function within an 'if' control?

jQuery Templates:

```
 {{if GetFirstWord(ProductName) == "Premier"}}
```

Native Templates (is this possible)

```
<!-- ko if: GetFirstWord(ProductName) == "Premier" -->
```

Also, can I access an indexer like this using native templating:

```
{{each(i, d) Benefits}}
  <div class="{{if i%2==0}}even{{else}}odd{{/if}}">
{{/each}}
```

Comment: About jQuery templates, notice that "the jQuery team has decided not to take this plugin past beta. It is no longer being actively developed or maintained".

Comment: Exactly why I'm moving the page to native templating

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First one: Yes, it's possible, and most likely you won't need to change much code. However, you *might* want to do anyway in order to suit a better architecture in KnockoutJS. It's not only for KO, but also a better design pattern that's more maintainable.

For instance, this

```
<!-- ko if: GetFirstWord(ProductName) == "Premier" -->
```

has the same functionality than

```
<!-- ko if: currentWordisPremier -->
```

and in your code you have something like

```
self.currentWord = ko.observable("");
self.currentWordisPremier = ko.observable(false);
self.currentWord.subscribe(function(newCurrentWord){
  if(newCurrentWord === "Premier") self.currentWordisPremier(true);
});
```

*(This was a quick example, you can design your code in a more scalable way through dynamic templating)*

Second one: Yes, but only from version 2.1 through the `$index` keyword. You can read more about the discussion [here](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/pull/182) and some documentation [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html).

As with the first point, you might want to change some of your javascript code to not give the template that much logic.

```
{{each(i, d) Benefits}}
  <div class="{{if i%2==0}}even{{else}}odd{{/if}}">
{{/each}}
```

in native KnockoutJS templating

```
<!-- ko foreach:Benefits -->
  <!-- ko if: $index %2 == 0 -->
  <div class="even"> ... </div>
  <!-- /ko -->
  <!-- ko ifnot: $index % 2 == 0 -->
  <div class="odd"> ... </div>
  <!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

a better approach could be

```
<!-- ko foreach:Benefits -->
  <div data-binding="css: {"even" isEven, "odd": isOdd}"> ... </div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

and you do the logic in your js, maybe just once for your array.

```
  var index = 0;
  var updatedBenefits = ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.Benefits(), function(benefit) {
     var property = index++ %2 == 0 ? "isEven" : "isOdd";
     return benefit[property] = true;
  });
  self.Benefits(updatedBenefits)
```

Comment: Hi jjperezaguinaga, thanks for your detailed and helpful response.